# Wait for callback from a fire and forget event in jest

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, async-await, jestjs, semaphore

I have a situation when building out an integration test in jest, where my product under test will call into a callback "at some point". The code under test is triggered by calling an event over an rpc "connection" (mocked out to be in memory messages), however the connection notification API returns immediately, rather than waiting for all async processes to stop.

So we have a setup like so:

```
test.tsx
//...preamble...
it('fire and forget with callback', async () => {
  const receivedRequests = [];
  clientConnection.onRequest(requestData => {
    receivedRequests.push(requestData);
    if (receivedRequests.length == 5) {
      signal.release();
    }
  });

  clientConnection.sendNotification(usefulTestData);
  // wait for a signal on 
  await signal.waitAsync();
  expect(receivedRequests).toEqual(expectedTestDataArrFromFile);
});

server.tsx
// ...preamble...

Server() {
// ...
    //onNotification handler callback's return type is void, not Promise
    this.connection.onNotification((notificationData) => this.handleNotification(notificationData));

    private async function handleNotification(data) {
      // do something interesting
      await this.connection.sendRequest(requestData);
      // do more...
    }
```

Here the `connection` object on both sides are different objects communicating via a mocked out RPC. The `sendNotification` on the client connection eventually calls into `onNotification` of the server, and vice versa.

Without changing the contract, how can I create a signal in the callback to only conditionally allow the test to continue executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

courtesy of inspiration found at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/issues/747

The following code is able to asynchronously wait on an event:

```
      const emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

      client.onNotification("textDocument/didOpen/processed", () =>
      {
        emitter.emit("notificationProcessed");
      });

      client.sendNotification(
        "textDocument/didOpen",
        openParams,
      );

      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        emitter.on("notificationProcessed", (_args) => {
          resolve();
        })
      });
```

here we have an event emitter that is fired once the fire and forget event completes.

The test context creates a new `Promise`, which will only resolve (and thus allow the test context to continue executing) once the the event has fired.